# Удаление из QPlainTextEdit задвоенных переходов на новую строку

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt, qplaintextedit

Как найти и удалить лишние переходы на новую строку?

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPlainTextEdit

class MainWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.plain_text = QPlainTextEdit(self)
        self.plain_text.appendPlainText("line one\n\nline two\nline three\n\nline four\n\n") 
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    w = MainWidget()
    w.resize(200, 100)
    w.show()
    app.exec()
```

Что бы итоговый вид текста в компоненте выглядел так:

```
line one
line two
line three
line four
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPlainTextEdit


class MainWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.plain_text = QPlainTextEdit(self)
        
        text = "line one\n\nline two\nline three\n\nline four\n\n"       # +++
        text = '\n'.join([line for line in text.split('\n') if line ])   # +++
        
        self.plain_text.appendPlainText(text) 
 
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWidget()
    w.resize(200, 100)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое! Я тоже наподобии такого думал, по итогу сделал, перед записью в компонент проверку на двойной переход и там же удаляю лишний